# How to use dynamic MPI_Type_create with MPI_Bcast?

Tags: c++, g++, mpi, mpich

So far I've been using `openmpi/1.10.2` with `gcc/5.3.0`, and my code has been working fine.

The cluster I'm working on changed its MPI implementation to `cray-mpich/7.5.0` with `gcc/5.3.0`, and I found the following error.

The compiler is preallocating local variables (`idx`, `disp`, `blocks`, and `types`) as `<optimized out>`. All the arrays are preallocated with `size == 2`.

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank;
    int size;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank); //passing the references
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size); //passing the references

    std::vector<int> mIntegers(0);
    std::vector<double> mFloats(2);

    if (rank == 0 )
    {
        mFloats[0]=1.0;
        mFloats[1]=1.0;
    }

    int ioRank = 0;
    int nBlocks = 0;

    if(mIntegers.size() > 0)
    {
        nBlocks++;
    }

    if(mFloats.size() > 0)
    {
        nBlocks++;
    }

    int idx = 0;
    MPI_Aint    displ[nBlocks];
    int         blocks[nBlocks];
    MPI_Datatype   types[nBlocks];
    MPI_Aint    element;

    // Create integer part

    if(mIntegers.size() > 0)
    {
        MPI_Get_address(mIntegers.data(), &element);
        displ[idx] = element;
        blocks[idx] = mIntegers.size();
        types[idx] = MPI_INT;
        idx++;
    }

    // Create floats part
    if(mFloats.size() > 0)
    {
        MPI_Get_address(mFloats.data(), &element);
        displ[idx] = element;
        blocks[idx] = mFloats.size();
        types[idx] = MPI_DOUBLE;
        idx++;
    }

    MPI_Datatype   paramType;

    // Create MPI datatype
    MPI_Type_create_struct(nBlocks, blocks, displ, types, &paramType);
    // Commit MPI datatype
    MPI_Type_commit(&paramType);

    // Broadcast the information
    MPI_Bcast(MPI_BOTTOM, 1, paramType, ioRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    std::cout<<"Process:"<< rank <<" of " << size << " F[0] "<<mFloats[0]<< ", F[1] "<<mFloats[1]<<  std::endl ;

    // Free the datatype
    MPI_Type_free(&paramType);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;

}
```

I've tried initialising the arrays with `new` setting them to zero and `std::vector` to avoid over-optimisation or memory leaks without any success.

The code is compiled with:

```
$mpic++ -O2 segFault.cpp -o segFault
```

and executed:

```
$mpirun -n 16 segFault
```

As a result `MPI_Bcast` leads to `segmentation fault` due to a mismatch of memory allocation.

MPICH defines `MPI_BOTTOM` and `MPIR_F08_MPI_BOTTOM`as

```
#define MPI_BOTTOM      (void *)0
extern int MPIR_F08_MPI_BOTTOM;
```

whereas open-mpi defines `MPI_BOTTOM` as

```
#define MPI_BOTTOM               ((void *) 0)          /* base reference address */
```

Comment: _"All the arrays are preallocated with size == 2."_ This is not what the code posted here does.

Comment: @HristoIliev that's what GCC does with -O2

Comment: It could be a bug in MPICH when dealing with `MPI_BOTTOM`. There was a similar problem in Open MPI that only got fixed recently.

Comment: @HristoIliev Is there anyway to check that? I'm using two BCast at the moment

Comment: Try with two arrays instead and see if it fails again.